# enable control button in rich:uploadFile

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I´m trying to re-enable the control button in a rich:uploadFile after upload the file.

I have:

```
<rich:panel id="fileuploader">
    <script type="text/javascript">alert("rendering");</script>
<rich:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadBean.listener}"
            maxFilesQuantity="1"   id="upload" autoclear="true"
            acceptedTypes="jpg, gif, png, bmp" >
            <a4j:support event="onuploadcomplete" reRender="fileuploader" />
    </rich:fileUpload>
    <a4j:commandButton value="reRender" reRender="fileuploader"/>
</rich:panel>
```

I put a Script to be sure the panel is re-rendering.
I read that you can reRender the uploadFile control, or refresh the whole page. After I upload the file, the controlButton gets disabled, and although I do a rerender with the commandButton, the control button is still disabled. But when I do a full refresh page, the control is ok.

Im using rich faces 3.3.3

Any help?

Thanks

[Edit]

I found the problem, but not the solution yet! I have a table with multiple rows so I have multiple rich:fileUpload's. If I just show one row and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've faced the same problem, to solve it I rerendered the control, not a panel that holds it, I don't know if this approach will work (but it does for me):

EDIT: Changed your code for mine, maybe there is a difference that I can't see.

```
<rich:fileUpload id="fuArchivoExcel" maxFilesQuantity="1"
    listHeight="60px" listWidth="350px" immediateUpload="false"
    fileUploadListener="#{cargaDocumentoRequerido.subeArchivo}"
    addControlLabel="Seleccionar archivo" uploadControlLabel="Subir"
    clearAllControlLabel="Borrar archivos"
    clearControlLabel="Borrar archivo" stopControlLabel="Detener" autoclear="true">
    <f:facet name="label">
        <h:outputText value="Se han subido {_KB}KB de {KB}KB" />
    </f:facet>
    <a4j:support event="onuploadcomplete" reRender="fuArchivoExcel,pnlMensajesError"
        oncomplete="finCargaArchivo('#{cargaDocumentoRequerido.mensaje.idMensaje}', '#{cargaDocumentoRequerido.mensaje.descMensaje}')" />
</rich:fileUpload>
```

---

EDIT (based in comments)

When you use the `<rich:fileUpload>` inside a repeater like `<rich:dataTable>`, you should rerender the repeater component instead of the single component. This will solve your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for me :( . I reRender the control but it has the same result

Comment: @OscarSan I've updated my answer using my own code. Maybe it could help you, if not, maybe I could pass you the jsp and the bean source.

Comment: Thanks. I have the same attributes ( almost the same Spanish labels xD) and it doesn't work

Comment: Really weird. There's no more code in my page than other controls (inputText, commandButton and all that). Maybe the difference is that my managed bean has request scope and the @KeepAlive annotation (but I'm not really sure).

Comment: I found the problem, but not the solution yet! I have a table with multiple rows so I have multiple rich:fileUpload's. If I just show one row and it works ... mmmm

Comment: Try rerendering the whole datatable.

Comment: No te preocupes, estamos para apoyarnos. Don't worry, be happy. Also, please edit your question so I can solve the problem in my answer, not in comments.